# simple perl assistance using hash values

Tags: facebook, perl

I'm very new to perl and am working with facebook authentication. This is the [cpan facebook library](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Facebook::Oauth2)

In it, during the `callback` i have the following code:

```
my $info = $fb->get(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/me?fields=birthday,email,name,id'   # Facebook API URL
);
```

This is the response from `$info->as_json`;

```
{"email":"someemail\u0040email.com","name":"some user","id":"fbid"}
```

I've tried accessing the values using `$info->email` and `$info->{email}` and `$info->{'email'}` into my debugger but im getting null values. How do i obtain these values from the `$info` variable (hash?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation to which you linked, the proper usage is

```
my $data = $response>as_hash;
$data->{email}
```

Comment: Looking at the source, `$fb->get` simply returns `$fb`! Weird. Of course, you shouldn't count on that since it's not documented.